# Editing URLs in Ruby in one go

Tags: ruby

I have a large string that goes like this:

```
"This is the text and this is a <a href='http://...' class='some_link'> link</a> that I would like to keep, however this is a <a href='http://...'>link with a keyword</a> that I would like to remove"
```

My objective is to substitute all URLS with '#' if there is a special keyword within the  tag.

Currently my actions are:

1. `arr = str.scan(/<a(.*?)a>/)` to find all the links in my string
2. `.join` each arr item and see if it `includes?` the keyword I am looking for
3. If yes, scan the whole body again and `gsub!` the url for #

Long, complicated, inefficient. Any idea how can I do this operation in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a solution using Nokogiri

```
html_links.xpath('//a').each do |link|
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use block version of `gsub`. It will pass each match to the block, from which you must return the replacement value.

Silly example:

```
replaced = 'Long, complicated, inefficient'.gsub(/\w+/) do |match|
  puts "match is: #{match}"
  if match.length > 5
    'big word'
  else
    match
  end
end

puts replaced
# >> match is: Long
# >> match is: complicated
# >> match is: inefficient
# >> Long, big word, big word
```